# Markov Chains: What is the difference between first passage time and hitting time?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

As stated in the title, what is the difference between first passage time and hitting time? The two definitions seem identical to me.

Comment: Most of the time they tend to be the same, but for example the first passage time through a boundary can potentially be different from the first hitting time of that boundary if it's possible to pass through the boundary without ever hitting it. (Of course that first passage time can then be viewed as the first hitting time of the domain on the other side of the boundary...)

Comment: It would help to give your two definitions to see where they might differ.